# Do I need <> after a SqlQuery<>(sql, parameters); when it returns nothing?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I am executing a query against a stored procedure:

```
var sql = @"dbo.sp_put_question_responses @AnswerGridResponses,
                                                      @UpdateRowCount OUT,
                                                      @UserId,      
                                                      @UserTestQuestionId";
            var parameters = new SqlParameter[]
                        {  
                            new SqlParameter("@AnswerGridResponses", answerGridResponses),
                            new SqlParameter("@UpdateRowCount", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output },
                            new SqlParameter("@UserId", userId),
                            new SqlParameter("@UserTestQuestionId", userTestQuestionId)
                        };

            var query = db.Database.SqlQuery<PutTestQuestionResponsesDTO>(sql, parameters);
            var putTestQuestionResponses = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            var updateRowCount = (int)parameters[1].Value;
            if (updateRowCount == 0) return BadRequest(); else return Ok();
```

The stored procedure is here:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_put_question_responses] 
    @AnswerGridResponses     VARCHAR(20),   
    @UpdateRowCount     INT OUTPUT,
    @UserId             INT, 
    @UserTestQuestionId INT
AS
BEGIN   
      UPDATE  UserTestQuestion      
      SET     AnswerGridResponses = @AnswerGridResponses,
              Answered = 1
      WHERE   UserTestQuestionId = @UserTestQuestionId
      AND     UserId = @UserId
      SET    @UpdateRowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

Previously it returned some data in a SELECT but now it returns everything through the parameters.

Can someone explain to me.  Now that I am no longer returning with a select what shall I put within the <> brackets here:

```
 db.Database.SqlQuery<PutTestQuestionResponsesDTO>(sql, parameters);
```

Do I even need to specify anything or should I write `<>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only two implementation of `SQLQuery<>` method as described in MSDN.

- [SqlQuery(String, Object[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545(v=vs.113).aspx)
- [SqlQuery(Type, String, Object[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679117(v=vs.113).aspx)

You are using first overloaded version of method.

**Definition**

```
public DbRawSqlQuery<TElement> SqlQuery<TElement>(
    string sql,
    params Object[] parameters
)
```

So from the definition it is clear that you are required to provide generic there so you would have to do like below.

```
SqlQuery<SomeClass>(sql, parameters);
```

You can use hack like providing empty class like `SqlQuery<SomeClass>(sql, parameters);`. But I am not sure whether it would result in  exception or not.

Or as an alternative you can just update stored procedure with some select statement like `select 1 from tablename`.

**Note:** last one is not recommended.

Comment: But why it is like this?

Comment: @Amit Simple because they have not developed method for such scenario where query would not select or return anything.

Comment: That i know. But what could be the reason behind that?

Comment: @Amit "The reason why so?" would be considered as broad topic and different person would have different answer based on imagination not based on fact. I believe that developer of that method might not have considered such a scenario.

Comment: Not convinced with that.